# Filter data based on condition from collection in the fastest way in Java

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, filter

I have a custom array list with almost 600 entries.

I need to filter some value based on some condition. I try basic loop stuff but its very time taking process, what I want is the fastest way to filter the data.

```
public class MyModel {
  private boolean attempeted = false;
  private String answer;

  public MyModel(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
  }

  public void setAttempted(boolean attempeted) {
    this.attempeted = attempeted;
  }

  public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
  }

  public boolean isAttempeted() {
    return attempeted;
  }

}
```

The above is my model what I want is I need to get only data having **attempted value true**. This is what I have:

```
ArrayList<TestAnswerModel>myMainArrayList=array which contain all my data
ArrayList<TestAnswerModel>filterArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<myMainArrayList.size();i++)
    {
        if(myMainArrayList.get(i).isAttempeted()) {
            filterArrayList.add(myMainArrayList.get(i))
        }
    }
```

The above is working fine but if my data is too large it takes a lot of time. Also some times the data will be 600 and the attempted value only true for 2 or 3 values so this looping will happen without any result.

What I want any fastest method to filter the data.

Comment: I suspect that problem with your other codes.  Because it should be really quick for 600 entries. Ok ..can you measure the time taking by loop by putting time logs ? (*measure time taking only by this loop, do not include your data fetching logic*)

Comment: is my above methord is the quickest way?

Comment: That's pretty much subjective question but could you please answer my initial question ?

Answer (score 3):

You want to collect all entries in your list that meet a certain condition. A sequential loop is basically the **quickest** way to get there. It doesn't make a difference if you expect 5% or 95% of your list elements to show up in the result list - you have to look at *all* entries to compute the result list!

Of course, you could turn to **[streams](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/)** and filtering - because that would allow you to use `parallelStream()` and process sections of list in parallel.

**But**: 600 entries is **nothing**. 600 elements are processed on modern hardware in a zillionth fraction of a wink.

So the **real** answer: don't worry about performance until it really becomes an issue. And then you **profile** your application to identify the **real** performance bottleneck to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can filter like this:

```
List<TestAnswerModel> filterArrayList = myMainArrayList.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.isAttempeted()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A list of 600 objects should filter through in an insignificant amount of time regardless of what approach you take. Like others have said, your performance issue probably lies elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @halfer, grammatically speaking yes but, `isAttempeted()` is how the OP defined the method in his class.